# OpenCV error - cannot put pipeline to play in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

I am trying to create video writer objects in OpenCV to write frames from my webcam into a file.  However I'm getting the following error on this line.

```
name1 = "videos/cam1.avi"
out = cv2.VideoWriter(name1,cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), 20.0, (1920,1080))
```

Error output:

```
File "TestWebcam.py", line 14, in takeImage
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(name1,cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), 20.0, (1920,1080))
cv2.error: /home/odroid/software/opencv/opencv-2.4.13/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1528: error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot put pipeline to play
 in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open
```

Comment: OpenCV is trying to use Gstreamer instead of FFMPEG. FFMPEG may be missing on your OpenCV build. Did you build opencv yourself? If so could you check if FFMPEG was enabled in cmake?

Comment: Yes, it was. Funny story, the code works perfectly for other files but fails for this one particular file. Trying to narrow the source of error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it by not using a path for `name1`.

See : [VideoWriter OpenCV - cannot put pipeline to play in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53210780/videowriter-opencv-cannot-put-pipeline-to-play-in-function-cvvideowriter-gstre)